# Getting IEEE754 byte representation from numpy

Tags: python, numpy, ieee-754

Is there a way using numpy to get a hex representation from a floating point value operation?  I'd like to avoid strings if at all possible.

for example:

`1.1` in single precision hex representation is `0x3F8CCCCD`

`1.1` in double precision hex representation is `0x3FF199999999999A`

Ideally I'd like to be able to do something like:

`numpy.function(value)`

returns

`hex representation`

Any good way to do this?

Comment: Not without using strings

Comment: What do you mean with "avoid strings" if you want the string representation of a number?

Comment: A hex representation only makes sense in the context of strings. What do you actually want to do? Print the hex representation? Store it as ASCII to disk? Manipulate individual nibbles (half-bytes) in the bit pattern?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `view` method of numpy arrays to do the equivalent of a C cast. Another approach is to use `float.hex` to give a more human-friendly hex representation than shown in the original post.

Example program:

```
import numpy as np
d = np.array(1.1)
i = d.view('int64')
print(f'double:      {d}')
print(f'cast to int: {i}')
print(f'hex:         0x{i.item():016x}')
print(f'floathex:    {float.hex(d.item())}')
```

Output:

```
double:      1.1
cast to int: 4607632778762754458
hex:         0x3ff199999999999a
floathex:    0x1.199999999999ap+0
```

Answer (score 0):

I can write a function that will give you the integer interpretation of the binary representation of the floating points as follows.

```
def to_words(x):
  ''' Gets the integer interpretation of the IEEE754 binary representation '''
  if x.dtype == np.float32:
    y = np.array(x);
    y.dtype = np.uint32;
    return y;
  elif x.dtype == np.float64:
    y = np.array(x)
    y.dtype = np.uint64;
    return y;
```

Maybe you can find a way to get the hex representation from there.

Comment: to the people asking about me avoiding strings.  I'm looking for a function like int(), or bin(), hex().  I understand it's a string representation but the actual object that's returned itself is still a number.  I'm looking for a function that will return single precision _numbers_ in hex form.

so `to_single(1.1)` would return `0x3F8CCCCD'

Comment: @lockecoleff: To be clear, you'd be happy if `print(to_single(1.1))` printed `1066192077`, right? That is, you actually want `to_single` to return an `int` (or perhaps a NumPy `int32` or `uint32`) rather than a string of any sort?

Comment: It's the "in hex form" part of your comment that's problematic - "in hex form" is a property of the string representation of a number, not of the number itself.